# vlc lua subtitle "reader"

Tags: scripting, lua, vlc, subtitle

I want to write an extension for VLC in Lua. I have never worked in Lua, and I can't find any information about this problem.

There is a function to get the current subtitle line directly (which is on the screen) ?

Another problem: 
What time of unit will be stored in this variable?

```
local elapsed_time = vlc.var.get(input, "time")
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything except a two year old post which might be relevant: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=102482.

About the `get` function, according to http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt it gets the `time` property of the `input` object. You would think it were same as `input.time` but maybe not.